# Wordpress - wp_nav_menu container_class not changing the container class

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am passing the arguments array to the header, like this:

```
<nav class="header__social-menu">
  <?php
    $args = array(
      'theme_location'  => 'social-menu',
      'container'       => 'ul',
      'container_class' => 'header__social-list',
      'link_before'     => '<li class="header__social-item"><a href="#" class="header__social-link">',
      'link_after'      => '</a></li>',
    );
    wp_nav_menu( $args );
  ?>
</nav>
```

But the container, which is the ul element, is not getting the class "header__social-list" assigned to it, but getting the class "menu" instead.

Is it possible to actually change the class of the container in order to stick with the BEM methodology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solved it by adding another agument, called "menu_class", so the code looks like this now:

```
<nav class="header__social-menu">
  <?php
    $args = array(
      'theme_location'  => 'social-menu',
      'container'       => 'ul',
      'container_class' => 'header__social-list',
      'menu_class' => 'header__social-list',
      'link_before'     => '<li class="header__social-item"><a href="#" class="header__social-link">',
      'link_after'      => '</a></li>',
    );
    wp_nav_menu( $args );
  ?>
</nav>
```

Not sure if i should leave the "container_class" argument there, but it is working with the "menu_class".

Answer (score 1):

This is what the wordpress documentation says about the `container` argument for menus:

> 'container' (string) Whether to wrap the ul, and what to wrap it with.
>   Default 'div'.

So that's to wrap the already generated `ul`, and `container_class` is for that wrapper, not for the `ul` itself.

But you might want to use `items_wrap` instead:

> 'items_wrap' (string) How the list items should be wrapped. Default is
>   a ul with an id and class. Uses printf() format with numbered
>   placeholders.

see also https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I see i had a misconception on what every argument does. So i removed the nav wrapping the arguments and added that as the container, and the container_class is now the class of this. The ul is automatically assigned and the menu_class is now the class of the ul element.
So sadly enough i cannot follow the BEM methodology that well, i'm just nesting the li and a inside of the ul which does has a BEM-like class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the first string array as `primary` that is the default name. Don't change the name because it will not work properly.

```php
register_nav_menus(
    array(
        'primary' => esc_html__( 'Primary Menu', 'wp' ),
    )
);
```